# Most well studied termite species or a species that I could use to compare termite genes for functional annotation

Tags: species

I am working with termites and I have a set of genes that I would like to compare with a species similar to termites so that I could elucidate its function. I am looking for a species that is similar to what *Drosophila Melanogaster* is to bees where to elucidate the functions of bee genes, it is compared to genes in *D. melanogaster*. Or how most worm genes is compared to genes in *C. elegans*. Similarly, if there is a well studied termite species, I could work with that.

The ultimate goal is to create a gene network with termite genes, hopefully on [STRING](https://string-db.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the most closely related insect to termites is cockroaches. [Interesting article](https://www.sciencenews.org/article/its-official-termites-are-just-cockroaches) I found on the subject. However, that still didn't help because cockroach genes are not included in the STRING database.